# Java android fragment take photo

Tags: java, android

In fragment I want to take a photo but I have a problem , I never get a callback to `onActivityResult`

**My code :**

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        int width = 960;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("error",ex.getMessage());
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = null;
                    try {
                        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        } else if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photoFile = null;

            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {

                mCurrentPhotoPath = photoFile;
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }



  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "smok" + timeStamp;
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                imagesDir /* directory */
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath = new File(image.getAbsolutePath());
        return image;
    }
```

`onActivityResult` never gets called. I kept break point on the first line of `onActivityResult` method  but it does not get called and I don't know why

Comment: put the log statement inside onActivityResult at first line

Comment: @RahulKhurana I put a log but it does not write

Comment: Are you testing it on device > Android M

Comment: @RahulKhurana API 26

Comment: Are you able to capture the picture via Intent?

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes ant I take a photo

Comment: @RahulKhurana but this method is not call never ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199172/discussion-between-kpokrywja-and-rahul-khurana).

Comment: I don't remember the exact details and it may vary by Android versions, but it could be because of not having something like `<uses-feature         android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i ahve this :     <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

Comment: onActivityResult is there in Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @ramyabr on fragment

Comment: Add it in Activity it will work.Callback comes to activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `Uri.fromFile(mCurrentPhotoPath)` but you should use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) instead use below code

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile)
```

**EDIT**

Don't forget to register for FileProvider in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

inside **res** package create a subfolder called **xml** and `provider_paths.xml`

`provider_paths.xml` content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->
    <external-path name="external_files" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

**EDIT 2**

You're passing newFile object inside FileProvider method. instead, use the one you already created. Also, you're using `getActivity()` as context you should fragment context instead. see below:

```
try {
    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Call `super.onActivityResult()` inside activity